# Configure the visibility permissions of single specific block inside Context (not using reaction)

Tags: blocks

I have a question about [Context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) and Block permissions.

The project has a context with a reaction that adds blocks. There are many blocks. I want to hide a single block for anonymous users.

My question is, can I configure individually the visibility permissions of the block?

I know that I can configure the context by a condition that does what I require, but this context have multiple URL, and would be a waste to create a new context just for a single block.

I have tried using [Block permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_permissions) and [Block Content Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_content_permissions). But, with no positive results (however, maybe I didn't know how to use well those modules).

[image]
[image]
[image]